# How do I achieve rowspan using bootstrap grid

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-plugins, zurb-foundation

I am trying to implement a stack something like:

http://homedepot.ca

Are they using a jQuery extension to achieve the effect of that layout, if so, which one? A quick peak at the source didn't tell me much...

It looks as though they may be using Foundation by Zurb  and not Bootstrap as I assumed initially. Perhaps a jQuery library called granite?

I want the left most column to assume all it's vertical and horizontal space, while the smaller right column will have 2 or 3 rows of much smaller images.

I need each cell to assume it's max width and height basically whilsty remaining responsive and collapsing vertically on smaller devices.

Any ideas?

Comment: Classes like 'col-sm-8 ' suggest use of Bootstrap. Why don't you take their site apart and with a tab open to http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid you should be able to work it out. By 'cell to assume its max width' I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Bootstrap cols have a width. You may mean something like set width:100% on content in a col? Basically - you can nest a Bootstrap row inside a Bootstrap col if that helps.

Comment: In general you should post code or a screenshot of what you want since this link can change at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They basically used something like this from Bootstrap with nested rows.
http://www.bootply.com/OCSQsH71zp

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">Something</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">Something</div>
            <div class="col-md-12">Something</div>    
         </div> 
  </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

You have two initial columns. In the right column, you add another row with two columns each spanning full width.

Comment: I thought so too - but I can't figure out how the left column assumes the height of both rows in the right column??? In tables this would be a breeze using rowspan

Comment: It's the same height as the "parent" containing both rows on the right side. If you have enough content or background, for example, to come all the way down and cover the same amount of real estate as both right side rows, then it'll look good.

Comment: In the example site you provided they are simply using absolute pixel height settings on the content in the columns to achieve the balanced layout mentioned by Rachel S. The height is not given by Bootstrap's grid system. The 'double-row' column has a div with height 544px. The content in the two rows on the right side use a class with 262px height on. The 20px gap must be similarly defined. I think a little more poking about in the Element Inspector may help you.

Comment: Actually we may perhaps all be assuming that the example site was built using a nested rows. However; on closer inspection it is one row. The right-hand column is just two elements each with a height which add up, together with a margin, to the height of the element in the left-hand column.